# After upgrading to ubuntu 20.10 xrandr fails to handle multiscreens

Tags: gnome, xorg, xrandr, citrix, beta

Environment: laptop in docker with external 3 screens connected
20.04 worked without issues.
20.10 seems to recognize and turn on laptop screen even if lid is closed. When I start citrix screens start to flicker, after a while x server restarts and citrix comes up on laptop screen that is closed sometimes.
What were exact change between 20.04 and 20.10 and how could I resolve this issue?

Thanks, Zoltan

Comment: You can easily resolve this issue by installing a stable release. This is a wrong place to report a bug.

Comment: @Pilot6 I guess Ubuntu 20.10 is a stable release. https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/groovy-gorilla-release-notes/15533

Comment: Oh, It was released today I guess ;-) What is your GPU? Did you install drivers?

Comment: I think it has a mobile intel driver. I never installed extra gpu driver for my laptop and was working without bugs.